# Angular website getting refreshed in an endless loop inside an Iframe tag

Tags: angular, iframe, clickjacking

We have an external angular website which we are trying to embed in our website using iframe.

Like this:

```
<iframe src="https://angular-website.com" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

When we render this page, nothing gets printed inside this 500x500 iframe and on checking the network tab, I can see the embedded website being called endlessly. I want the website to load just one once and be visible inside the iframe.

What could be the issue? Let me know if you need more info.
Thanks!